# how to open new Web page with that Row details when click that Row's Link button inside the Kendo UI Grid Field in Asp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I searched Over the Google, i didnt get my Requirement, My Screen Like
[image]

if i click the System Name Means i want to display the row details in another Web page how to do it?
My COde Like'

```
      var grid= $("#DivGrid").kendoGrid(
            {
                dataSource: DataSource4,
                  scrollable: true,
                sortable: true,
                filterable: false,
                reorderable: true,
                   resizable: true,
                pageable: true,

                toolbar: [ { text : "Add new record", name: "popup", iconClass: "k-icon k-add"} ],
           editable  : {
                     mode : "inline"  
//                template: kendo.template($("#customPopUpTemplate").html())
                  },

                navigable: true,
                     columns: 
                          [  {
                        field: "SystemName",
                        title: "System Name",
                        width:"130px",
//                        template: '<a href="\\#" id="Link1" onclick="NewWindow()" class="k-Linkbutton" >#= SystemName #</a>'
template:'<a href class="list k-Linkbutton"  id="#= SystemId#" >#= SystemName #</a>'
//                         headerTemplate: ' <asp:linkbutton id="LinkButton2" Text="System Name">System Name</asp:linkbutton>' 

            },

                         {
                        field: "SystemIP",
                        title: "System IP",
                          width:"100px"
    },
                    {
                        field: "SystemType",
                        title: "Type",
                        width:"80px",
                        editor: function (container, options) {
                        $("<input />")
                        .attr("data-bind", "value:SystemType")
                          .appendTo(container)
                           .kendoDropDownList({
                         dataSource: [ { text: "--Select--" ,value: "0"},{ text: "PC" ,value: "1"},{ text: "LAPTOP" ,value: "2" }],
                    dataTextField: "text",
                    dataValueField: "text"
                });
        }
    },
                    {
                        field: "OSKey",
                        title: "OS Key",
                        width:"200px"
                    },

          { 
                 command: ["edit","destroy"], 
                       title: "&nbsp;", 
                        width: "190px" 
                    }       
                ]
            }).data("kendoGrid");
```

I want to display the Row details in another wen page i don't have any idea ? i searched Google But i didn't Get,
help me how to do ?
thanks in advance!!!

Comment: How about using `window.open`